# refreshing a div using ajax, my div didn't refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, partial-page-refresh

after deleting some data using ajax, i want to refresh my div. I am using Laravel 5.4 . I am a beginner in laravel. Please help me about this.

This is my code in refreshing a div :

```
var url = window.location.href;
function RefreshDiv() {
    $(".uploaded-images").fadeOut();
    $(".uploaded-images").load(url+" .uploaded-images", function() {
      $(".uploaded-images").fadeIn();
    });
}
```

When i execute the `RefreshDiv` function , it only makes my div empty, but when i press `f5` to refresh my page, it successfully deleted my data. My only problem is my `RefreshDiv` where i wan't it to refresh my div but it gives me empty div.

Here is my delete function that executes well:

```
function deleteImage(product_img_id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "{{ url('admin/del-img') }}/" +product_img_id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      RefreshDiv();
    }
  });
}
```

here is my div that i want to refresh:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
          <h5>Uploaded Images</h5>
          <div class="uploaded-images">
          </div>
</div>
```

inside of my uploaded-images div , is a delegate function from my other ajax.

Here is my delegate function :

```
function getProductDetails(product_id) {
    $( ".uploaded-images" ).empty();
    $.ajax({         
        url: "{{ url('admin/get-product') }}/" +product_id,        
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
for(var i=1;i<data.product_images.length;i++) {
                 $(".uploaded-images").append('<div class="img-wrap">'+'<span class="close">&times;</span>'+'<img src="'+"{{ asset('image_files') }}/"+data.product_images[i].product_image+'" data-id="'+data.product_images[i].product_img_id+'" style="max-height:50px; max-width:90px;">'+'</div>');
            };   
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Have you selected it properly? `$(".uploaded-images")` returns **all** elements with `.uploaded-images` class.

Comment: @PredatorIWD thanks for fast response. Here is my div, my div contains delegate jquery elements

Comment: how does url look like?

Comment: @brk hello sir i edited my post. please take a look. thanks for your fast response

Comment: The issue seems to be with this line `load(url+" .uploaded-images"`. `.uploaded-images` is a class selector. You can open developers console -> network tab and check the url which you are trying to hit.Check if the url is valid

Comment: @brk it gives me status code:200 sir where it means, it successfully get my url, by the way sir, my .upload-images is inside my modal

Comment: @brk it only fades out but fades in doesn't

Comment: what's return body of  `url+" .uploaded-images"` and it would aso help if you update the OP to show your entire url (by replacing `url`  variable)

Comment: @NishanthMatha http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/product. btw my .uploaded-images is inside a modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to refresh the div...If you're removing the image why not just remove the element on success from DOM?

Try this:

```
function RefreshDiv(product_img_id) {
   $("img[data-id="+product_img_id+"]").closest('.img-wrap').remove();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function deleteImage(product_img_id) {
  $.ajax({
   url: "{{ url('admin/del-img') }}/" +product_img_id,
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "JSON",
   success: function(data) {
    RefreshDiv(product_img_id);
   }
 });
}

var url = window.location.href;
function RefreshDiv(product_img_id) {
   $(".uploaded-images img[data-id="+product_img_id+"]").parent().remove();
   $(".uploaded-images").load(url+" .uploaded-images", function() {
   $(".uploaded-images").fadeIn();
 });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but, u don't understand my question well. My problem is about when i delete an image where function deleteImage after it success, i put another function there to refresh my div. thats my problem sir.

Comment: Try the above script. may be this code helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: opps still nothing.. i dont know why

Comment: use this code. send me the console log of image element  length.
 function RefreshDiv(product_img_id) {
      console.log( $(".uploaded-images img[data-id="+product_img_id+"]").parent().length)
       
    }

Comment: it gives me in console : 1

Comment: function RefreshDiv(product_img_id) {
    $(".uploaded-images").fadeOut();
   $(".uploaded-images img[data-id="+product_img_id+"]").parent().remove();
   $(".uploaded-images").fadeIn();

}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154636/discussion-between-santho-and-jc-john).